# NuGet install-package error (unable to find version that is compatible)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, nuget-package

I'm trying to install `Xamarin.Forms` package, however, the console throws this error

```
Install-Package : Unable to find a version of 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design' that is compatible with 'Acr.UserDialogs 6.3.8 
constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (>= 23.3.0 && < 26.0.0)', 'Xamarin.Forms 2.4.0.282 constraint: 
Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (= 23.3.0)'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Xamarin.Forms
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

I understand that some packages aren't compatible, I tried to install them individually, tried to changed the target API level, nothing.

So my question is, how can I install `Xamarin.Forms` inside the `package manager` terminal without getting those errors?

I'm new to Android development in Xamarin.

Comment: Can you try a clean project to install Xamarin.Forms first, and then install other packages? That might avoid some conflicts.

Comment: You mean like **New Project** or `Build > Clean` option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by using `NuGet` the GUI way.